# Groovy read file line by line, eachLine method uses BufferedReader

Tags: groovy

I have written a groovy script to read a huge file line by line.

I currently am using boilerplate code as follows

```
File hugeFile = new File(filePath)
if (hugeFile.exists()) {
    hugeFile.eachLine {line ->
        //some process
    }
}
```

My question is how do I find out if the "eachLine" is using a BufferedReader to be memory efficient ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Give it a shot to see if it can handle big files.

And check the [source at github](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/IOGroovyMethods.java#L471):

```
public static <T> T eachLine(Reader self, int firstLine, @ClosureParams(value=FromString.class,options={"String","String,Integer"}) Closure<T> closure) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br;
    int count = firstLine;
    T result = null;

    if (self instanceof BufferedReader)
        br = (BufferedReader) self;
    else
        br = new BufferedReader(self);
    ...
}
```